# Formatar casas decimais no forms

Tags: c#, string, formatação

Preciso formatar as casas decimais e não consigo.
Qual a maneira correta de fazer a formatação neste caso?

```
 double peso, altura, imc;
        string nome;

        nome = txtnome.Text;
        peso = Convert.ToDouble(txtpeso.Text);
        altura = Convert.ToDouble(txtaltura.Text);

        imc = (peso) / (altura * altura);

        if(imc < 18)
        {
            //lblimc.Text = String.Format("{ 5.2 } ", imc);
            //lblimc.Text = String.Format("{0:#.#,##}", imc);
        }
        else if(imc >= 18 && imc <= 24.9)
        {
            lblimc.Text = (nome + " seu IMC é "+ "\n" + imc + " você está no peso ideal!!");
        }
        else if(imc >= 25 && imc <= 29.9)
        {
            lblimc.Text = (nome + " seu IMC é " + "\n" + imc + "você está acima do peso ideal!!");
        }
        else if(imc >= 30 && imc <= 34.9)
        {
            lblimc.Text = (nome + " seu IMC é " + "\n" + imc + "você está na obesidade de 1º grau!!");
        }
        else if(imc >= 35 && imc <= 39.9)
        {
            lblimc.Text = (nome + " seu IMC é " + "\n" + imc + "você está na obesidade severa!!");
        }
        else
        {
            lblimc.Text = (nome + " seu IMC é " +  "\n" + imc + "você está em obesidade mórbida!!");
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Se você quer garantir que o formato seja este que você disse em qualquer computador precisa dizer qual a cultura a ser usada no código:

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", 43239.11));
```

Precisa usar o namespace `System.Globalization`.

Answer (score 4):

Não consegui identificar o formato que voce deseja, mas de qualquer forma, uma maneira de formatar é com o especificador "N" e também, caso queira ter maior consistência, pode usar o CultureInfo para um formato especifico de algum pais por exemplo.

Obs: com o CultureInfo é necessário importar o `System.Globalization`

```
double value = 10002.22644123;
Console.WriteLine ($"{value:N2}"); // 10,002.23
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"))); // 10.002,23
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // 10,002.23
```

Pode ver mais sobre na [documentação da formatação padrão](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) , ou caso queira algo mais custom pode ver na [documentação custom](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).